# Does our arrangement of a sentence that has a participle clause in it, affect its meaning?

Tags: sentence-structure, present-participles, participles

Q. So, what're you doing tomorrow?
A. I'll stay in watching the soccer match.

Now, if we rearranged the answerer's answer to **I'll watch the soccer match staying in**, would it mean the same as his original answer?

**I was walking the streets of my neighborhood, looking at the various shops at the sides of the streets.**

Does the above sentence mean the same as

**I was looking at the various shops at the sides of the streets, walking the streets of my neighborhood.**

My question is, does our arrangement of a sentence that has a participle clause, in it affect its meaning?

Comment: So as not to introduce new variables, why not make the sentences actually parallel?  I'll be *watching*...staying in.  I was looking...walking

Comment: Also, watching and *staying in* are not really concurrent activities, as looking and walking are. Remaining at home is closer to a state than an action.  But your second example of watching/looking versus looking/watching are both viable, The sequence of data is different and so there must be some difference, but the effect of sequence on the totality of the meaning is *de minimis*.  I think we could argue that the second clause is the "incidental" action not the primary action.